# Instagram filter integration my project but run my project then only normal filter call and other call then some issue (below mention)

Tags: ios, image, instagram, instagram-api

> CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This
>   application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is
>   thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and
>   reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It
>   will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Please help me.